# Plotly: How to remove empty dates from x axis?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

*I have a Dataframe*

```
   Date        Category    Sum
0  2019-06-03    "25M"      34
1  2019-06-03    "25M"      60
2  2019-06-03    "50M"      23
3  2019-06-04    "25M"      67
4  2019-06-05    "50M"     -90
5  2019-06-05    "50M"     100
6  2019-06-06    "100M"     6
7  2019-06-07    "25M"     -100
8  2019-06-08    "100M"     67
9  2019-06-09    "25M"      450
10 2019-06-10    "50M"      600
11 2019-06-11    "25M"      -9
12 2019-07-12    "50M"      45
13 2019-07-13    "50M"      67
14 2019-07-14    "100M"    130
15 2019-07-14    "50M"      45
16 2019-07-15    "100M"    100
17 2019-07-16    "25M"     -90
18 2019-07-17    "25M"     700
19 2019-07-18    "25M"     -9
```

I want to create a plotly graph showing the addition of "Sum" for different "Category" on Every described date,  but want to remove dates, if they don't have any data.

**Code**

```
df["Date"]=pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format=("%Y%m%d"))
df=df.sort_values(["Date","Category","Sum"],ascending=False)
df=round(df.groupby(["Date","Category"]).agg({"Sum":"sum"}).reset_index(),1)


fig = px.bar(df, x=df["Date"] , y='Sum',barmode="group",color="Category") 
fig.update_xaxes(
rangeslider_visible=True,
rangeselector=dict(
    buttons=list([
        dict(count=1, label="day", step="day", stepmode="todate"),
        dict(count=24, label="montly", step="month", stepmode="todate"),
        dict(count=1, label="year", step="year", stepmode="todate"),
        dict(step="all")
    ])
   ))


fig.show()
```

[image]

*I am getting graph like this but I want to remove the empty Dates from the plotly graph*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plotly: How to remove the empty gap on x-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59021060/plotly-how-to-remove-the-empty-gap-on-x-axis)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had the same problem with my graph. Just add the following to layout code:

```
xaxis=dict(type = "category")
```

Note: I have used `import plotly.graph_objs as go`
and **NOT** `import plotly.express as px`

This worked for me. Hope it helps you too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this useful answer. It worked very well in my chart.

Comment: Using rangebreaks(as in accepted answer) in large volume of data resulted in slow loading of the candlestick graph. This worked for me very well. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know what exactly that line does?

Comment: Where to use this param `xaxis`?

Comment: @Deshwal `fig.layout = dict(xaxis=dict(type="category"))`

Comment: Did not work for `5, 15` minutes data. Any idea why?

Comment: Thank you! When working with Plotly Express objects, you can use fig.update_xaxes(type = 'category').

Comment: Great answer, but problem is that xaxis tick labels changes with type='category'.

Answer (score 9):

This problem comes from the fact that plotly interprets your `'Date'` as *dates* and creates a continuous period between the oldest and newest timestamp, effectively showing dates with no associated data as gaps. One solution is to take the first and last date in your date column, and make a *complete* list of dates in that period, and then sort out which dates *do not* have any observations, and store that in a variable named `dt_breaks`. Then, at last, you can include those dates in:

```
fig.update_xaxes(
    rangebreaks=[dict(values=dt_breaks)] # hide dates with no values
)
```

This will drop those dates in your visualization, *and* keep the x-values formatted as dates so that you can subset the data using your buttons:

[image]

And here, as you already know, is the same visualization without `rangebreaks=[dict(values=dt_breaks)]`:

[image]

To make this work as simply as possible, I rearranged the date column using `df=df.sort_values(["Date","Category","Sum"],ascending=True)` instead of `df=df.sort_values(["Date","Category","Sum"],ascending=False)` as in your original code snippet

**Complete code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': {0: '2019-06-03',
                          1: '2019-06-03',
                          2: '2019-06-03',
                          3: '2019-06-04',
                          4: '2019-06-05',
                          5: '2019-06-05',
                          6: '2019-06-06',
                          7: '2019-06-07',
                          8: '2019-06-08',
                          9: '2019-06-09',
                          10: '2019-06-10',
                          11: '2019-06-11',
                          12: '2019-07-12',
                          13: '2019-07-13',
                          14: '2019-07-14',
                          15: '2019-07-14',
                          16: '2019-07-15',
                          17: '2019-07-16',
                          18: '2019-07-17',
                          19: '2019-07-18'},
                         'Category': {0: '"25M"',
                          1: '"25M"',
                          2: '"50M"',
                          3: '"25M"',
                          4: '"50M"',
                          5: '"50M"',
                          6: '"100M"',
                          7: '"25M"',
                          8: '"100M"',
                          9: '"25M"',
                          10: '"50M"',
                          11: '"25M"',
                          12: '"50M"',
                          13: '"50M"',
                          14: '"100M"',
                          15: '"50M"',
                          16: '"100M"',
                          17: '"25M"',
                          18: '"25M"',
                          19: '"25M"'},
                         'Sum': {0: 34,
                          1: 60,
                          2: 23,
                          3: 67,
                          4: -90,
                          5: 100,
                          6: 6,
                          7: -100,
                          8: 67,
                          9: 450,
                          10: 600,
                          11: -9,
                          12: 45,
                          13: 67,
                          14: 130,
                          15: 45,
                          16: 100,
                          17: -90,
                          18: 700,
                          19: -9}})

df["Date"]=pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format=("%Y-%m-%d"))
df=df.sort_values(["Date","Category","Sum"],ascending=True)
df=round(df.groupby(["Date","Category"]).agg({"Sum":"sum"}).reset_index(),1)



dt_all = pd.date_range(start=df['Date'].iloc[0],end=df['Date'].iloc[-1])
dt_obs = [d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for d in df['Date']]
dt_breaks = [d for d in dt_all.strftime("%Y-%m-%d").tolist() if not d in dt_obs]

df=df.set_index('Date')

#fig = px.bar(df, x=df.index.strftime("%Y/%m/%d") , y='Sum',barmode="group",color="Category") 
fig = px.bar(df, x=df.index , y='Sum',barmode="group",color="Category")

fig.update_xaxes(
    rangebreaks=[dict(values=dt_breaks)] # hide dates with no values
)


fig.update_xaxes(
rangeslider_visible=True,
rangeselector=dict(
    buttons=list([
        dict(count=1, label="day", step="day", stepmode="todate"),
        dict(count=24, label="montly", step="month", stepmode="todate"),
        dict(count=1, label="year", step="year", stepmode="todate"),
        dict(step="all")
    ])
   ))


fig.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

For skip empty dates, hours, you should use:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig.add_trace(go.Candlestick(x=df['begin'], ...)

fig.layout = dict(title=ticker, xaxis = dict(type="category", categoryorder='category ascending'))
fig.show()
```

This example works good.
Good luck

Answer (score 2):

In case, someone is here playing with stocks data, Below is the code to hide outside trading hours and weekends with rangebreaks.

```py
    fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=df['date'], open=df['Open'], high=df['High'], low=df['Low'], close=df['Close'])])
    fig.update_xaxes(
        rangeslider_visible=True,
        rangebreaks=[
            # NOTE: Below values are bound (not single values), ie. hide x to y
            dict(bounds=["sat", "mon"]),  # hide weekends, eg. hide sat to before mon
            dict(bounds=[16, 9.5], pattern="hour"),  # hide hours outside of 9.30am-4pm
            # dict(values=["2020-12-25", "2021-01-01"])  # hide holidays (Christmas and New Year's, etc)
        ]
    )
    fig.update_layout(
        title='Stock Analysis',
        yaxis_title=f'{symbol} Stock'
    )

    fig.show()
```

here's [Plotly's doc](https://plotly.com/python/time-series/#hiding-weekends-and-holidays).

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to add to Mega J's answer. First acquire a list of market holidays in your date range like so:

```
xnys = xcals.get_calendar("XNYS", start=import_start, end=import_end)
holidays = pd.to_datetime(xnys.day.holidays)
holiday_mask= (holidays > import_start) & (holidays <= import_end)
hols = holidays[holiday_mask].strftime("%Y-%m-%d").tolist()
```

Copying Mega J's code from above and adding the holidays to rangebreak:

```
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=df['date'], open=df['Open'], high=df['High'], low=df['Low'], close=df['Close'])])
    fig.update_xaxes(
        rangeslider_visible=True,
        rangebreaks=[
            # NOTE: Below values are bound (not single values), ie. hide x to y
            dict(bounds=["sat", "mon"]),  # hide weekends, eg. hide sat to before mon
            dict(bounds=[16, 9.5], pattern="hour"),  # hide hours outside of 9.30am-4pm
            dict(values=hols)  # hide market holidays inside your date range
        ]
    )
    fig.update_layout(
        title='Stock Analysis',
        yaxis_title=f'{symbol} Stock'
    )

    fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto the answer from vestland above this worked great for me:

```
fig.update_xaxes(
    rangebreaks=[dict(values=pd.date_range(start="2023-05-28",end="2023-06-09"))] # hide dates with no values
)
```