# Strange behaviour of dates in plotly chart

Tags: python, date, charts, plotly

I have a plotly chart showing the months like this with this code:

```
    fig.update_layout(
        title=title,
        autosize=False,
        width=1280,
        height=720,
        xaxis_tickformat='%B',
        yaxis=dict(showgrid=False),
    )
```

[image: Chart with correct dates]

But when I try to solve the problem of days without data, the format of dates change and I can0t find a way to solve it... any ideas?

```
    fig.update_layout(
        title=title,
        autosize=False,
        width=1280,
        height=720,
        xaxis_tickformat='%B',
        xaxis=dict(type="category",
                   showgrid=False,
                   ),
        yaxis=dict(showgrid=False),
    )
```

[image: Dates issue]

Seems that type="category" is the origin of the issue.

**EDIT**:

I've tried to use type='date' but then I see days blank days.   I also deleted blank days using:

```
    fig.update_xaxes(
        rangebreaks=[
            dict(bounds=["sat", "mon"]),  # hide weekends
            dict(values=["2022-05-30"]),  # hide Memorial day
        ]
    )
```

But this is not useful for a dynamic chart where I've new holidays every year...  I also don't want to create a whole new list of dates, seems strange there is no way to **just change the dateformat!!**

thanks

Comment: Rather than set type as category, specify which dates to not plot. See @vestland's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61924649/17142551)

Comment: Try this: `type='date'`

Comment: type='date' is the first image you can see here.  It's full of blank dates and gaps between candles.

Comment: The vestland solution is hard to implement and reduces the performance of the code when you have to plot thousands of charts, which is my issue...